# Criar título para duas colunas

Tags: html

Tenho este código para criar as seguintes tabelas lado a lado:

```
echo '<div><table border="1"><tr><td>';
echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições Creche I Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela1;
echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições Creche II Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela2;

echo "</td><td>";

echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td ><h5><strong>Total de Refeições Infância Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela3;
echo '<div><table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td ><h5><strong>Total de Refeições Infância Colaboradores</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela4;

echo "</td><td>";

echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições Centro de Dia Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela5;
echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições Centro de Dia Colaboradores</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela6;

echo "</td><td>";

echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições Lar Utentes</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela7;
echo '<table border="1" style="width:150px"> <td style="width:20px; text-align: center"><h5><strong>Total de Refeições Lar Colaboradores</strong></h5></td> ';
echo $tabela8;

echo '</td></tr></table></div>';
```

Resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora pretendo criar um título para as duas primeiras tabelas lado a lado e outro para as outras duas, como mostro na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para fazer uma *célula* da tabela ocupar mais que uma coluna, pode usar o atributo [`colspan`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_colspan.asp). Caso queira que ocupe mais que uma linha, também pode usar o [`rowspan`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_rowspan.asp), como mostra o exemplo abaixo.

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Senior</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```